# Error C3872 y C2065 no puedo acceder al subíndice [i-1]

Tags: c++

Estoy probando un ejemplo del libro "Programming:principles & practice with C++" de B.Stroustrup, pero el compilador de visual studio 2015 no se traga el intento de acceder al subíndice[i-1] de un vector...y sin el fichero de encabezado std_lib_facilities.h el compilador tampoco me acepta el algoritmo sort()... se puede descargar aquí: 
http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }


// simple dictionary: list of sorted words
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
       words.push_back(temp); // put into vector
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
    sort(words); // sort the words
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) 
        if (i == 0 || words[i–1] != words[i]) // is this a new word?
            cout << words[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Que errores te muestra el compilador?

Comment: Sin el fichero de encabezado me muestra los errores c2672, c2780 y c3872; con el fichero de encabezado del libro me muestra C3872 y C2065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código encontré dos errores

#### error 1

La función `sort` requiere 2 o 3 parámetros, donde los dos primeros son el inicio y el fin de `vector`, y el tercero (opcional) es una función binaria que retorne true si el primer parámetro debe ir primero que el segundo.

#### error 2

El signo de la expresión  `words[i–1]` tiene un caracter *dash* en lugar de un signo de menos, la diferencia es bastante dificil de apreciar, por eso los coloco uno junto al otro:

1. `words[i–1]` incorrecto
2. `words[i-1]` correcto

#### Código

Por lo tanto el código corregido es el siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; }


// simple dictionary: list of sorted words
int main()
{
    vector<string> words;
    for (string temp; cin >> temp; ) 
       words.push_back(temp); 
    cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
    sort(words.begin(), words.end()); // sort requiere 2 (o 3) parámetros
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) 
        if (i == 0 || words[i-1] != words[i]) // cambiar el caracter por "–" "-"
            cout << words[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: El error 2 es bastante sutil, muchas gracias!

Comment: Otra cosa que me acabo de dar cuenta, revisa en la instrucción `if (i == 0 || words[i-1] != words[i])` el orden de precedencia, debido a que `||` tiene **menor** precedencia que `!=`